# Error due to And statements in C in MingW compiler

Tags: c

I've started using notepad ++ to write C and mingW to compile it for my university course. Im making a program that tells you whether you have an even number or odd number of arguments. Any arguments over 10 it says there are too much. However, i keep getting an error message saying "error: expected identifier before "("" and it points at the bracket before arg%2. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc ==1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"You need to give some arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if (arg < 11)&&(argc%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("There is an odd number of arguments\n");

    }
    else if (argc%2 == 1) 
    {
        printf("There is an even number of arguments\n");

    }
    if (argc > 11)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Too many arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Typo: you need `else if (arg < 11 &&argc%2 == 0)`.

Comment: C does not have an `and` statement`. `&&` is not a statement.

Comment: yh thanks juan that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `if` is:

```
if ( condition )
```

followed by either `else` or a statement-block.  Your code does not match this syntax, so you are getting a syntax error.

You could write:

```
if ( (arg < 11)&&(argc%2 == 0) )
```

optionally without the inner sets of parentheses. `&&` has lower precedence than the other operators involved there, but some consider it adds clarity to use the parentheses anyway.

Answer (score 1):

M.M is correct.
The lack of parenthesis makes the compiler prematurely end evaluation of the if statement. It would read the Line 12: "arg < 11" then stop.

Also!
Don't forget to correct the spelling, some of the calls to argc were incorrectly typed as just 'arg'. ex. Line 12, "(arg < 11..."
If you submitted (to SE) your code word-for-word, this is surely one compile error.